# Jenkins Mutualize SCM polling

Tags: jenkins

Using Jenkins, I am running 2 builds (Linux+Windows) and one Doxygen job
At the moment, I am using 3 separate SCM polling triggers pointing to the same source code

**How can I use a single trigger for all three jobs** provided that I still want to get separate statuses

For the record; the underlying SCM is Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, some solutions which might do what you are looking for:

- Instead of setting an SCM trigger, use a post-receive hook in your repository, which can send a signal for Jenkins that there are new changes (see: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository). This way Jenkins doesn't have to constantly poll the repository (multiple times for the different jobs), and the trigger would be faster, since there is no waiting for the next polling, but when there is a push, a build will be started.
- Use an extra job, that would do nothing else, just have the SCM polling trigger, and start all three original jobs (without waiting for any of them to finish).
- If the configuration is similar for all three jobs, you could consider creating a single project with a [matrix configuration](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project). Roughly what it does, is that you could have a variable for the build type, with values like linux, windows, doxygen. When the job is triggered, it would start multiple builds with all the possible values - of course you would have to set up the job in a way that the current parameter changes the build process according to what needs to be done. Actually I haven't had to use a matrix configuration yet, so my example may be not the best, but you can probably find lots of examples on the Jenkins wiki, if you think this is a good direction.